# Listening to ConsoleTraceListener logs from Node

Tags: c#, node.js, stdin, spawn, tracelistener

I have written sample application which prints the logs to `ConsoleTraceListener`.

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y5y10s7(v=vs.110).aspx), the `ConsoleTraceListener` should redirect to standard output. I `spawn` this process from node and trying to listen to `stdout` and it's unable to get the information.

Any idea how to fix this? I want to stream `TraceListener` to node

C#:

```
Trace.Listeners.Add(new ConsoleTraceListener(true));
Trace.AutoFlush = true;
Console.WriteLine("This comes out");
Trace.WriteLine("oops");
Trace.TraceInformation("Getting lost");
Thread.Sleep(5000);
Console.WriteLine("Stopping comes out");
```

Node:

```
let proc = ps.spawn("sample.exe");
proc.stdout.on('data', (c) => {
    console.log(c.toString());
});

proc.stderr.on('err', (c) => {
    console.log(c.toString());
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you redirect to stderr, not stdout, because of parameter you pass to `ConsoleTraceListener`:

```
Trace.Listeners.Add(new ConsoleTraceListener(useErrorStream: true));// < note true here
```

To redirect to stdout - change that to false:

```
Trace.Listeners.Add(new ConsoleTraceListener(useErrorStream: false));
```

Then you will see the output in your node.js app.
If you want to see stderr, change your node.js app like this:

```
proc.stderr.on('data', (c) => {
    console.log(c.toString());
});
```

Then you will see output even with your original .NET application which writes to stderr.

If the above does not help - check if you define TRACE compile-time constant (project properties > checkbox "Define TRACE constant").